# What is a vector of vector of point?

Tags: c++, vector, point

Consider the following definition:

```
vector < vector < Point > > convexHulls(contours.size());
```

I know vector has the ability to resize itself automatically when an element is inserted or deleted.

But I don't understand what this vector can store?

Also why there are two vectors? `vector < vector` and what is `Point`?

Comment: This should be of use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: A `vector` can store any other type of object. You need to tell the `vector` what type of object it is storing when you specify it. A `vector` of `int`s is different than a `vector` of `double`s, for example. In this case, this function `convexHulls`, returns a `vector` of `vector`s of `Point`s. The library you're including should specify what a `Point` is.

Comment: For example, `vector<int>` can store `int`s. In general case, `vector<T>` stores `T`s. `vector< vector<Point> >` thus stores *vectors* of `Point`. It's sort of a 2D vector (but each sub-vector can have different length).

Comment: @QuattronTech There is no type named `Point` in C++. From context, we can guess that it is a user defined class. It must have been defined somewhere else in the program.

Comment: @eerorika  vector < vector < Point > > contours;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A vector is a templated class that can store anything that you ask it to store when you defined it.  For example:

```
vector<int>      // vector that will store any number of integers
vector<double>   // vector of double precision floating points
vector<string>   // vector of strings
vector<T>        // vector of Ts, being understood that T is a type
```

In your case you have a `vector < vector... >` which means that you have a vector of vectors.  In practice it's a 2D data structure that is sometimes used to implement a matrix.

```
vector<vector<int>>    // vector of vectors, aka 2D vector of integers
vector<vector<Point>>  // 2D vector of Points, where Points is a type, probably a class
```

Example:

```
vector<vector<int>> m { { 1,  2,  3,  4}, 
                        { 5,  6,  7,  8},
                        { 9, 10, 11, 12} };
cout << m[1][2]<<endl;  // line 1, item 2 (numbering start with 0) -> 7
```

Now, you have to look in your source code where `Point` is defined.  If the code compiles, it must be defined somewhere.  Very probably it's something like:

```
struct Point { int x, y; };
```

Comment: this was used to define   vector < vector < Point > > contours;

Comment: @QuattronTech ok.  And the `convexHulls` is created with the same number of items (in this case lines) as `contours`.  But each line is made of a vector of 0 elements that will either be resized or push_back()ed.